# How to define the association table as pojo entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, pojo

I have 3 tables in the db. I am trying to write the JPA entities. I am facing some issues with Association table entity. My entities are as follows,

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
//setter and getter
}
```

**Exam.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exam")
public class Exam {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long examId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String examName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int marks;
    //Setters and getters
}
```

The table structure for association table is,

```
create table person_exam (
        personId BIGINT not null,
        examId BIGINT not null,
        primary key (personId, examId)
    );
```

I tried the association table entity with @ManyToMany annotation for both the properties which is not giving me the result.

Can anyone please suggest me what should I need to use (ManyToMany/OneToOne/ManyToOne/OneToMany ) in my entity for the above person_exam table.

Comment: All JPA implementations have documentation that explain easily enough how to have a 1-N/M-N relationship. Suggest that you read one

Answer (score 0):

from the PRO JPA 2nd Ed. book:

> the only way to implement a many-to-many relationship is with a separate join table. The consequence of not having any join columns in either of the entity tables is that there is no way to determine which side is the owner of the relationship. Because every bidirectional relationship has to have both an owning side and an inverse side, we must pick one of the two entities to be the owner.

So I chose the the Person entity. Applying the needed changes to your incomplete code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    /**
     * we need to add some additional metadata to the Person designated 
     * as the owner of the relationship, also you must fully specify the names of 
     * the join table and its columns because you already provided a schema 
     * for the association table, otherwise the JPA provider would generate one.
     */
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="person_exam",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personId"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="examId"))
    private Collection<Exams> exams;

//setter and getter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "exam")
public class Exam {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long examId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String examName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int marks;
    //Setters and getters


    /**
     * As in every other bidirectional relationship, 
     * the inverse side must use the mappedBy element to identify 
     * the owning attribute.
     */
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="exams")
    private Collection<Person> people;
}
```